# Is there a homeomorphism from the space of sequences to [0,1]?

Tags: analysis

If I consider the norm for the space of sequences of digits {0-9} to mimic the norm for real numbers.

$|\left\{x_n\right\}| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{10^n}$

shouldn't I now have a space identical to [0,1]?

Comment: What kind of sequences are you considering? Are you looking at sequences with values in $0,\dots,9$ and not infinitely many repeating nines?

Comment: I'm not sure.  If I exclude trailing 9's, shouldn't I exclude trailing 9's from [0,1] also?

Comment: It might be necessary to exclude them though to get one-to-one... so yeah but if I stick with insisting it's a norm and just say that trailing 9's is equal to another sequence?  Wouldn't that work just as well?

Comment: If $x_n$ are restricted to integers only then there is a bijection from the sequence space to R. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226723/is-this-set-bijective-to-r. To get a bijection from R to [0,1] see this trick here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080815000752AAZTABY. Finding a homeomorphism is more difficult of course, and although I am no expert, it looks to me that there is no continuous bijection between [0,1] and R, and so you cannot use my results very usefully...

Comment: wouldn't the norm induce the same metric as in real numbers?

Comment: I am asking: What is the distance between (1,1,1,1,...) and (0,1,2,3,4,...) (for example) ? So is it: 1+ 1/10 + 2/100 + 3/1000 + ... ? Or is the integer 12 not allowed to be a numerator in your sequence space? There is a problem here because 12/20 equals 6/10 and 6/10 looks like it can be in your sequence, but 12/20 can not... More importantly, can 0.824756248756... be a member of one of your sequences?

Comment: @user54358 I update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in this case.

By [Cantor diagonal methold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) ( or [Dedekind cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) )  we can identify $\mathbb{R}$ and space of sequence  $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}^\mathbb{N}$. By $[0,1]\ni x \mapsto \tan(x\cdot \pi)\in\mathbb{R}$ we cam identify $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}^\mathbb{N}$ and $[0,1]$

Comment: So the norm/metric should be defined by: $|\left\{x_n\right\}| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{10^n}$ (provided that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{10^n}$ exists)

Comment: @AdamRubinson I update my answer.

Comment: Your function is not continuous. I think you meant f(x) = tan((x-1/2)pi), in which case I think the only problem is sequences like (0,9,9,9,9,9,...) and (1,0,0,0,0,...)  which are not the equal, although 0.999... and 1 are equal and so injectivity is the problem now.